# Boolean Equation Transformation

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra

Can someone show me the steps in getting from $f = (ab + c')(d' + e + f')$ to $f = abe +ab(df)' + c'e + c'(df)'$? I am trying to relearn Boolean algebra after a long hiatus.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$
\begin{align}
f & = (ab + c')(d'+e + f') \tag{1}\\ \\
f & = (ab + c')(e + (d' + f')) \tag{2} \\ \\
f & = (ab + c')(e+(df)') \tag{3}\\ \\
f & = abe+ ab(df)' + c'e + c'(df)' \tag{4} 
\end{align}$$

$(3) \;\;d'+f' = (df)': \text{DeMorgan's}$

$(4)\;\; \text{Distributive Law}$

Comment: Very clean and so nicely lined up! +1